# Compare values with a given standard row by row and write just 1 number for each row (exceeds / doesn't exceed the standard)

Tags: r, threshold, continuous

I have a matrix with many rows. Let's say

```
M = matrix(1:20, nrow = 4, ncol = 5)
```

And I have a threshold variable, e.g.

```
threshold = c(4,7,11,14,17)
```

Now I want R to compare each row in the matrix with this threshold value by value and tell me whether at least one value in that row exceeds this threshold's corresponding value. I.e., M[1,1] should be compared with threshold [1], M[1,2] with threshold [2] etc.

Ideally I would like to have a new variable, let's call it check, with just 1/FALSE (there is at least 1 value in the row exceeding the threshold) or 0/TRUE (no such values).
Till now, what I could program is this:

```
check = apply (M, MARGIN=1, (ifelse((M[,] < threshold), 1, 0)))

check = apply (check, MARGIN=1, sum)

check = check == 0
```

But there are 3 problems with it:

1. Maybe it's not the best way to solve the problem? I have a lot of data, and I think it can work very slowly..
2. It doesn't work, R says:

   > check = apply (M, MARGIN=1, (ifelse((M[,] < threshold), 1, 0)))
   >   Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
   >     '(ifelse((M[, ] < threshold), 1, 0))' is not a function, letter or symbol
3. Even if I perform just

   ifelse((M < threshold), 1, 0)

for the first row I get

```
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0
```

Which is not true, because there are no values in the first row that exceed the threshold. It seems that R just compares the whole first row with the 1st element of threshold, then the whole 2nd row with the second value etc., and that's not what I want...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think, for (3), you are getting the result because the first row of M looks like `1 2 3 4 5` and neither 4 nor 5 are < the lowest value in threshold `4`

Comment: But matrix is created column by column, so the first row is (1,5,9,13,17), not (1,2,3,4,5)
...

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17
[2,]    2    6   10   14   18
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apply(M, 1, function(x) max(diag(sapply(x, function(y) y >threshold))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

```
rowSums(t(M) > threshold) >= 1
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

To see it row-by-row just do,

```
t((t(M) > threshold)*1) #---> ...* 1 just converts from logical to integer

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    1
#[3,]    0    0    0    1    1
#[4,]    0    1    1    1    1
```

Based on your comment,

```
as.integer(rowSums(t((t(M) > threshold) * 1) > 0) > 0)
#[1] 0 1 1 1
```

Comment: Sorry, but I want it to be compared row by row, i.e., I should get 4 values at the end (one for each row). In your example, I get 5 values, because it compares column by column

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You also have 5 values for the first row... `1    1    1    0    0`

Comment: @AlexM please have a look now. The calculations were correct. There was just another step to get the logical (or binary) as to which row has any value greater than its threshold.